# App Inventor 2 - UPDATE SQL: Fusion table

Tags: sql, sql-update, google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

I'm trying to update a single field in an fusion table using AppInventor. I have successfully obtained the rowid using a select query and stored this value and displayed in a label.

I then want to update a field for this row using the rowid obtained but the rowid is being stored as 'rowid 1001' and not just '1001'

Any suggestions on how I can just have the value of the rowid and not the column heading as well will be greatly appreciated.

Snippet = Do It Result: UPDATE  SET 'Name'='Tim' WHERE ROWID = 'rowid 1001'

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you get back from the fusiontable is always a table in csv format, in your case it is a 1 column csv table which looks like this

rowid
1001

the first row is the header row, the second row is the rowid you are looking for.
Now just split the result using the `split` block at `\n` (new line) to get a list with 2 items. The rowid you are looking for is the second item in that list.

[image]